# setting the function initializer of weights in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to initialize the weights in tensorflow.js with only positive value but it seems that I never give it the "correct" shape. here is my code:

```
let data_size = 500;
let input = [];
let output;
const model = tf.sequential();

for (var i = 0; i < data_size; i++){
    input[i] = i;
}

input = tf.tensor2d(input, [data_size, 1]);
output = tf.add(tf.scalar(1), input);

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 6, activation: "relu", inputShape: [1], weights: tf.randomUniform([6, 1], 0, 1)}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: "linear"}));

model.compile({loss: "meanSquaredError", optimizer: "adam"});
```

so in my code, in the first layer that I am adding, I put the "weights" parameter to choose the initialization of the weights https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#layers.add

but even if the shape of the weights would be [6, 1], it doesn't take it. I tried tf.randomUniform([1], 0, 1) too as it could be a single expression passed to all the weights but it doesn't work either. How do you choose the expression to initialize the weights with tensorflow.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weights` is an array of tensors according to the [doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#layers.add). The layer is initialized in this way **A**X + **B**. So one needs to provide the **A** and **B** tensors (where X is the input to the layer).

```js
let data_size = 500;
let input = [];
let output;
const model = tf.sequential();

for (var i = 0; i < data_size; i++){
    input[i] = i;
}

input = tf.tensor2d(input, [data_size, 1]);
output = tf.add(tf.scalar(1), input);

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 6, activation: "relu", inputShape: [1], weights: [ tf.randomUniform([1, 6], 0, 1),  tf.randomUniform([6], 0, 1)]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: "linear"}));

model.compile({loss: "meanSquaredError", optimizer: "adam"});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```